# How to convert an already NA stored values to an actual NA value in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am working on a dataset where the column of gender has almost 120 NA's, and I thought those were actual NA's, but they aren't, and they are coming into my model when I don't need them.

I changed the gender to a factor, and then checked the levels, this is the output:

`levels(data$Gender)`

`[1] "Female" "Male"   NA` 
Because NA here is not in inverted commas, I assumed it is not a factor level, but it is!

Then i tried to see if it actually is NA and tried:
`is.na(data$Gender)`

And all the values are false! That means they are not being read as `NA` by R.

So, i tried converting them with:

`data <- data %>% mutate(Gender = ifelse(Gender == "NA", NA, Gender))`

And what this is doing is converting my factor variable into a numeric variable and assigning my genders with 1,2, and 3. 3 for NA.

So, of course I tried the simplest method

`data[data == "NA"] <- NA`

This of course did not work either.

Then i tried:

`replace_with_na(data, "Gender", .x~ == "NA")`

and this does not work either.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Neither do I understand why the `is.na()` output is `FALSE` despite the `levels` command not putting it in inverted commas ("") like it does with female and male, nor do I understand my failure to convert them despite all efforts.

Comment: Tip: for single-line `code formatting`, use single backticks, not triples.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it's better to not convert to `factor` until you remove the contaminating values. Otherwise you have to remove those levels later.

Second, in case you have something other than `"NA"` in that column, you can simply replace everything that is **NOT** the desired values so you don't have to enumerate all the possible wrong values.

```r
x <- sample(c("M", "F", "NA"), 10, T)
x
#>  [1] "M"  "M"  "M"  "NA" "F"  "NA" "M"  "NA" "NA" "F"
x[!x %in% c("M", "F")] <- NA
x
#>  [1] "M" "M" "M" NA  "F" NA  "M" NA  NA  "F"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Would this translate as ```data$Gender[!data$Gender %in% c("M", "F")] <- NA``` because that is not working either. It is still NA. And I just saw that gender is a factor in my original data structure without me tweaking it

Comment: back to square one to nothing working

Comment: It does let me filter just males and females, but I do not want to lose the data of those 120 people in the other relevant columns.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try importing your data again with `fread() from data.table with stringsAsFactor = FALSE`? If you data is a factor, then you can try reading it as non factor (just an idea). Since we don't have your data frame cannot test my ideas.
Check `stringr` package to replace/remove NAs with `str_*` functions

a simple DF with NAs can work with filter:

```
dx <- read_table(col_names = T,
  'Gender Col1 col2
    Male   1   2
    NA    3    4
    NA    5     6
    Female 8    9')

    
    dx%>%filter(is.na(Gender))
```

Comment: would filter not reduce my data, i tried filter and it gets rid of the 120 people with NA. And i do not want to discrard good data in the other columns. Also, it's a .csv file, I dont know how exactly would that work on it

Comment: Filter was just to show that is.na() working and treating NA as NA. Thats what you need, no? If it's csc file, read data with fread or read.csv functions.